# MVC - Given a route name, can I get the default action name and controller name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Given a route name, can I get the default action name and controller name?

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "MonthlyCalendar",
      url: "FMB/Calendar/{jamaatName}/{year}/{month}",
      defaults: new { controller = "FMB", action = "MonthlyCalendar", 
         jamaatName = UrlParameter.Optional,year = UrlParameter.Optional,
         month=UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Comment: I've removed the duplicate sentence from your question, which reduces it to a oneliner that doesn't really show what you have tried. Can you update your question with that? It also seems to be a duplicate of [Get "Default" Route Url in Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356725/get-default-route-url-in-controller).

Comment: At runtime? From where/what context?

Comment: I am inside a controller action.. And i Have a route name with me..

Comment: i have update the question with the route i have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>No, of course that you cannot get controller and action name from just a route name. A route mapping might look like this: `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. That's the only thing you could get if you only have a route name.</strike>

If on the other hand you have a full url such as `http://example.com/Home/Index` then this is an entirely different story. Now you can get the controller=Home and action=Index from the RouteData.

---

UPDATE:

It seems that you are attempting to extract the default values for the controller and action from your routing configuration given the route name. This can easily be done by storing the route name when registering it in the DataTokens property:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "foo",
    "{controller}/{action}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
).DataTokens["__RouteName"] = "foo";
```

and then:

```
var route = RouteTable.Routes.OfType<Route>().FirstOrDefault(x => 
    x.DataTokens.ContainsKey("__RouteName") && 
    (string)x.DataTokens["__RouteName"] == "foo"
);
if (route != null)
{
    var defaultController = route.Defaults["controller"];
    var defaultAction = route.Defaults["action"];
}
```

The reason why you need to store the route name in the DataTokens is because this 
information is not available in the Route instance.

---

UPDATE:

At some point MS added an indexer to `RouteCollection` to lookup by name, so the above is no longer necessary:

```
 ((System.Web.Routing.Route)Url.RouteCollection["MyRouteName"]).Defaults
```

You should probably check first to make sure it exists to avoid null exception.

Comment: why not? the route has some defaults defined in it.. why cant I access it ?

Comment: No my route mapping has a controller name and action name defined in it as defaults

Comment: So you want to access the default values of your routing configuration? That's what you should have written in your question because this is very confusing. I will update my answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, is this __RouteName some Microsoft's intrinsic or reseved value specific to MVC, like Namespace or UseFallbackNamespace, or is it something that you made up? I'm asking this because on MS platform they usually use this double underscore convention for internal usage.

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic, no, absolutely not. It's me putting it there so that I can retrieve the route by name later. Look at my route definition. And I need to put it there coz the guys at Microsoft didn't do it which is a shame - according to their understanding of things a route can perfectly fine live without a name. And if you give it a name it is not part of the route but is stored in some internal hashtable.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I saw the route definition. That is why I asked. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3):

I've created this extension method that adds the "active" css class to a route link.  This method gets the default action and controller from the route based on route name, if an action and controller is not provided in the RouteValueDictionary.

You can get the default action from the route in the `RouteTable`, however you need to cast the return value as `Route` instead of `RouteBase`.

**Example:**

```
var action = (RouteTable.Routes["Default"] as Route).Defaults["action"] as string;
```

**Full Extension Method:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuRouteLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    string currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

    var route = RouteTable.Routes[routeName] as Route;
    if (route != null)
    {
        routeValues = routeValues ?? new RouteValueDictionary();
        string routeAction = (routeValues["action"] as string ?? route.Defaults["action"] as string) ?? string.Empty;
        string routeController = (routeValues["controller"] as string ?? route.Defaults["controller"] as string) ?? string.Empty;

        if (routeAction.Equals(currentAction, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && routeController.Equals(currentController, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            htmlAttributes = htmlAttributes ?? new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var currentCssClass = htmlAttributes["class"] as string ?? string.Empty;
            htmlAttributes["class"] = string.Concat(currentCssClass, currentCssClass.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty, "active");
        }
    }

    return htmlHelper.RouteLink(linkText, routeName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the RouteData that is supposed to serve your request by reading `ControllerContext.RouteData`. `RouteData` object has `Values` which in turn has `Keys` that you can examine and apply to Values to get all the fragments of the route.

Normally, you can loop through `RouteCollection` (this depends in which context you are located, eg. ViewContext, or using HtmlHelper object) and extract each item and cast it to `Route` object. After that call `Route.GetRouteData(YourHttpContextBaseHere)` which return `RouteData` or null. If it returns an object, that `Route` served your request and examine `Defaults` property.

For example, lets say you are building an HTML helper and you have access to HtmlHelper object. THe following code shows you what you could do:

```
var defaults = (RouteValueDictionary) null;
foreach (var routeBase in html.RouteCollection)
{
    var route = (Route) routeBase;
    var routeData = route.GetRouteData(html.ViewContext.HttpContext);

    if (routeData != null) 
    {
        defaults = route.Defaults;
        break;
    }
}

// Do something with defaults object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into `System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes`. It contains all routes in system. But you don't find **default** action and controller if they are not specified